# Artifactory - Generic Repo: Archive download failing

Tags: artifactory

### Scenario

Attempting to curl archive from generic repository in Artifactory which worked for me the past few days.

### Code

```
curl -i -H 'X-JFrog-Art-Api: <api-key>' -XGET https://<host>/artifactory/api/archive/download/<repo-name>/<dir>?archiveType=zip -o <out-file>
```

### Problem

Today I tried running my curl command again and I get the below error

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 09 Mar 2017 13:49:14 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Artifactory/4.16.0
X-Artifactory-Id: <removed>
X-Artifactory-Node-Id: <removed>

{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 400,
    "message" : "There are too many folder download requests currently running, try again later."
  } ]
}
```

### Question

How can I resolve this, I have tried waiting it out but it's been more than 12 hours since I cannot pull down what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message indicates that you have more than 10 concurrent download requests for folder archives. This is the default configuration, but it can be altered.
You can [configure](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Artifactory#ConfiguringArtifactory-FolderDownloadSettings) the max number of concurrent folder download in Admin > General Configuration > Folder Download Settings > Max Parallel Folder Downloads.

Comment: Yes, this is what was needed to be done and our folks tuned the settings. Thanks for the reply.